What graphs allow alternate movement of pieces?
Suppose I have two white and two black pieces, each located at a distinct vertex of a finite connected bipartite undirected graph G.
From a start position S we play a co-operative game, alternately moving a white piece to an adjacent unoccupied vertex, and then moving a black piece and so on until with a final black move we reach an end-position T.
Two pieces can never occupy the same vertex or capture one another.
Say a game from S to T is cool if we might alternately reach T from S with a journey that involved black moving first and white moving last.
Are there necessary and/or sufficient conditions on the connectivity of G such that all games, for all possible S and T, are cool?
Feel free to make S fixed if that works better.
Motivation: This abstract question comes from analysis of a game, but seems mathematically interesting in its own right. An elegant answer here could massively reduce computer search. I don’t know of any results in this area. I’m sure that one could vary the number of pieces of each colour but two seems enough to generate sufficient complexity.

You have used the term "unoccupied square" instead of "unoccupied vertex". Is this "lapsus linguae" meaning that you are thinking mainly to the case of a checkerboard (a particular case, indeed, of a bipartite graph). Whence my question : is the case of a checkerboard, a "cool" case (pun intended) ?

Hi @JeanMarie good catch. I have fixed the typo, and another. A checkerboard with orthogonal connectivity is one example that one might explore. The uniformity of the results of our computer exploration suggests that a simple theorem might be lurking here at a more abstract level than a particular board

"reach $T$ from $S$ with a journey that involved black moving first" seems to be equivalent to "return from $T$ back to $S$ by the same rules". If we define the directed graph of all possible positions, this is equivalent to positions $S$ and $T$ being in the same strongly connected component of that directed graph. (One thing to immediately note is that this is an equivalence relation; so if all games from $S$ to other positions are cool, then all games are cool.)
